# PHP security updates in Debian after PHP version EOL

Tags: debian, security, php, software-updates

I got a quite stupid question I am afraid but I am kind of in need of written confirmation of my suspicion.

Consider a `Debian 9` with PHP from the official repositories. The PHP version shipped by `Debian 9` is `7.0`.
I did not enable third party repositories such as [Sury](https://deb.sury.org/).

In my research I found the [Debian PHP documentation](https://wiki.debian.org/PHP) which gives all the information I could need except for the following question: **What happens, when the PHP version is not maintained upstream any more?**

The PHP Project states in their [supported versions document](https://www.php.net/supported-versions.php), that PHP 7.0 does not receive security updates since the beginning of 2019. **So is the default PHP version in `Debian 9` potentially vulnerable?**

Thanks in advance for any input and information!

Comment: The PHP version packaged with a new Debian release is nearly out of date (ie unsupported by PHP maintainers). It becomes unsupported before a new Debian version is released. Debian officially encourages people not to go to outside sources for software for security reasons. If you follow Debian and PHP maintainer's advice you can not implement PHP on Debian securely. This is why I reluctantly switched to Ubuntu as a server for PHP websites.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The PHP packages are covered as part of [Debian Stretch LTS](https://wiki.debian.org/LTS/Stretch), until June 2022, on the LTS architectures (`i386`, `amd64`, `arm64`, `armel` and `armhf`). Ondřej Surý backports security fixes from later releases, see [his July 6 upload](https://tracker.debian.org/news/1158167/accepted-php70-7033-0deb9u8-source-amd64-all-into-oldstable-proposed-updates-oldstable-new-oldstable-proposed-updates/) for a recent example.

If you install the `debian-security-support` package, you’ll be told if your system uses any unsupported package.

Comment: I was unsure which answer to mark as correct as both provide a valid answer, but after your edit this is definitely the more comprehensive answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Debian 9.0 is currently supported.

PHP7.0 in Debian 9.0 does receive security fixes: https://metadata.ftp-master.debian.org/changelogs//main/p/php7.0/php7.0_7.0.33-0+deb9u8_changelog

TLDR: You're safe as long as Debian 9.0 is supported.